# SpringBoot Session Management

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, spring-security

I have a SpringBoot application and looking to handle user sessions, but the code I have does not seem to work.

```
 http
        // session management
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
        .sessionFixation().changeSessionId()
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
        .expiredUrl("/index.html")
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

// Work around https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2855
@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
    return sessionRegistry;
}

 // Register HttpSessionEventPublisher
@Bean
public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}
```

The above work-around was provided on the JIRA ticket, but I can still log-in multiple times with the same username and password, how can I prevent it?

Am using Spring-Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE

> Update 01

```
    @EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Order(2)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationSecurity.class);

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http
            // session management
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .sessionFixation().changeSessionId()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .expiredUrl("/index.html")
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

        http
            // login management
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/index.html")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .failureUrl("/index.html")
            .permitAll();
        http
            // logout management
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/index.html")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        SecurityConfigurer<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> securityConfigurerAdapter = new XAuthTokenConfigurer(
                userDetailsServiceBean(), authenticationManagerBean());

        http.apply(securityConfigurerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean(name = "myAuthManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    // Work around https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2855
    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
        return sessionRegistry;
    }

    // Register HttpSessionEventPublisher
    @Bean
    public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
}
```

Comment: And how are you testing this?

Comment: @M.Deinum, manually from two different machines/same machine two browsers.

Comment: Please post your full security config, because I suspect you are still using the Spring bOot default and your config is basically ignored.

Comment: Is your form login working? Also why is your login-url the same as your logout-url? It also looks like you aren't overwriting Spring Boot  security settings as mentioned [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html) so that might be interfering. You also have 2 `@EnableWebSecurity` annotations

Comment: @M.Deinum, yes the login and logout work fine, The EnableWebSecurity was a mistake (copy-paste), the 1st like should be commented. Will look at the security settings and let you know. Also is there any example around where I can refer to?